# How to get window height in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I 'm using iframe to display the contents using angularjs with ionic framework. Here, I need to give window height as iframe height, so I have used

```
  $scope.iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

But, I am getting 1/4th screen only.

Here what I tried so far.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
    <head>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs CSS -->
    <link href="css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionic-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js bundle -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" ng-style="{height:iFrameHeight}" id="iframeid" width="100%" ></iframe>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: tpyo: `iFrameHeight` !== `iframeHeight`

Comment: Small point - to avoid testability problems down the line, I would add a $window argument to your function and use $window.innerHeight instead.

Comment: is window.innerHeight a custom function?  I can't find documentation on it.

update:  got it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Main problem: you need to add 'px' units to `window.innerHeight` number. And the second one, variable name is `iframeHeight` not `iFrameHeight`. Fixed expression will look like:

```
ng-style="{height: iframeHeight + 'px'}"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NdQB5afQT7kMkf27k7wg?p=preview

Comment: Great! kudos to you :)

Answer (score 6):

The window object, although globally available has testability issues as reference in the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window .It looks like its not an issue on your code though but for good practice, you can inject a $window service then reference that instead and of course the "px" issue on the bottom.

```
   angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']) 
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) { 
   $scope.iframeHeight = $window.innerHeight;
     });
```

Later, as said before;

```
  ng-style="{height: iframeHeight + 'px'}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Since *AngularJS* contains a small part of *jQuery* by itself you can use:

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$scope.iframeHeight = $(window).height();
```

or

```
// Returns height of HTML document
$scope.iframeHeight = $(document).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Calculte windows height using angular**

```
$scope.screenHeight = '';
$scope.calculateoriginalWidth = function() {
    var width = $window.innerWidth;
    $rootScope.originalWidth = width;
}
$scope.calculateScreenHeight = function() {
    var height = $window.innerHeight;
    var width = $window.innerWidth;
    var subheight = 0;
    var headerheight = document.getElementById('headerTitle1');
    var headerheight2 = document.getElementById('headerTitle2');
    if (headerheight) {
        subheight += headerheight.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (headerheight2) {
        subheight += headerheight2.offsetHeight;
    }

    $scope.screenHeight = height - subheight - 20;
    $rootScope.screenHeight = $scope.screenHeight;
    $scope.screenWidth = width;
    $rootScope.screenWidth = $scope.screenWidth;
}

var reg = $scope.$on('screenResize', function($evt, args) {
    $scope.calculateScreenHeight();
    $scope.$apply();
})

window.onresize = function(event) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.calculateScreenHeight();
    })
};

$scope.calculateScreenHeight();
$scope.calculateoriginalWidth();
```

You need to add the required dependencies in angular for using this code. Hope this will help you to calculate the height of the window.